# Displaying own gigapixel images in DeepZoom using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image-processing, imaging, deepzoom

I actually use my own code to produce the images(tiles)at different layers of the pyramid (ones  which are otherwise produced by deepzoom composer).I want to know if it is possible to load them in silverlight? usually on the net I have seen images exported out of deep zoom composer for this and hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single large image its reasonably easy if you already have the pyramid set of tile images for the image.

**The Xml**

Create yourself a sub-folder (under ClientBin usually) to contain your set of large images (lets just call it "Content" for this example).  Create in this folder an Xml file to describe your deepzoom image, for this example "MyLargeImage1.xml".  Use this following Xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Image TileSize="256" Overlap="1" Format="jpg" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008">
    <Size Width="40000" Height="30000" />
</Image>
```

Note the `TileSize` attribute indicates the side length of the tiles that you have used.  Hence if you have used a different tile size in creating your pyramid then you should adjust this value.  Note also `Overlap`, this indicates by how many pixels each tile may overlap, if you haven't used any overlap in your tiling set this value of 0.

Specify the actual pixel dimensions of your image in the `Size` element.

**The Image Files**

Now in the same folder as this Xml file create a folder with the same title but with the suffix "_files".  In this case a folder called "MyLargeImage1_files".  Its in this folder that we have a series of sub folders representing the pyramid layers.

In the case of a Gigapixel image (such as with the dimensions I have used above) you would have 17 folders, named from "0" to "16".  Since you would need to down to level 16 to view such an image at its native resolution.

Each of these folders you would contain the set of tiles that make up this layer in the pyramid.  These are .jpg files with a file title of the form "x_y" where x and y are the tiles ordinal position in the x and y axis, where 0_0 is the top left tile.

In this example all folders upto and including "8" would contain a single 0_0.jpg file since its only above level 8 would we find images larger than the 256 limit for a single tile that is specified in the Xml.  Of course if you have used a different tile size then this will differ for you.

By level "16" you would expect to have all files from 0_0.jpg to 156_117.jpg (18526 files is a lot of files for single folder).

**The Xaml**

Finally to actually display the image you use the `MultiScaleImage` control and point its source property at the xml file:-

```
<MultiScaleImage Source="/Content/MyLargeImage1.xml" />
```

Comment: I tried stuff pretty similar to what you said.However if I create my own XML it doesnt seem to laod anything .However if I copy the XML from one of the previous versions it seems to work (it actually superimposes this new image on the older one) .My point is when none of my folders under source contain this old image how does it show in the browser.My second approach primarily comes from the fact that I cant get a xml written from scratch to work.

Comment: @Manish:  Get a copy of http://www.fiddler2.com/ and monitor the requests coming from Silverlight when you use your own XML.  Remember that the urls are relative to the ClientBin folder, e.g. / = the ClientBin folder itself.